# ipmitool getsysinfo command failed

Tags: dell-poweredge, ipmitool

I'm trying to get the `delloem_url` property of a Dell PowerEdge R410 server with `ipmitool`, but it fails with message:

```
getsysinfo command failed: Requested sensor, data, or record not found
```

I recently installed XenServer 7.0 on this server, but `ipmitool -I lanplus -H <ip> -U root -P <password> mc getsysinfo os_name` for some reason still shows `Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation (x64) Edition`. (I do not know if is related, but just in case)

How can I get the remote control url of the server?

Comment: Can you please provide the full command ?

Comment: In the second command, is <ip> the idrac address or the serveur address ? I guess it's the idrac that shows "Windows Server ...". This value is the latest value set by the OMSA agent installed on the windows server. To update this value, you should install OMSA on the new operating system.